# How can custom Hooks in React have different state names then the state name used by the functional component from which it was called?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Firstly, Here is the working code:

#App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useCounter = ({ initialState }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialState);
  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const decrement = () => setCount(count - 1);
  return [count, { increment, decrement }];
};

const App = () => {
  const [myCount, { increment, decrement }] = useCounter({
    initialState: 0
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{myCount}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here, "useCounter" is the custom hook and I'm calling it from the App component.
In the App component, I'm naming my state value as "myCount" and in the "useCounter" function, I'm using "count" as the state name. Till here it's fine. Though when I return 2 functions "increment", and "decrement" having this return value: `setCount(count + 1)` from the "useCounter" function, So how does the returned function works in the App component when I called increment and decrement like this:
`<button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>`. Isn't my state name in App component is "myCount" but the function definition of increment uses "count" name,  `const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);`. How is this possible? I have tried running this code and it works perfectly fine. "myCount" values gets increment and decrement correctly.

Comment: Are you basically asking "How it is possible that my value named `myCount` while the function using the name `count` and it works?"

Comment: yes, How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to React but to the basics of Javascript, [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

---

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

In your custom hook `useCounter` you return an array.

Using the syntax above, you rename the values:

```
// useCounter
return [count, { increment, decrement }];

// Destructuring Assignment
const [myCount, actions] = useCounter();

// Same Logic
[a, b] = [10, 20];
[ten, twenty] = [10, 20];
```

---

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

Therefore, you have closures on `count` value in `increment`/`decrement` scope.

---

In conclusion, you can rename your `count` name and use it due to closures.